# Tinycore: Non-frugal install of Tinycore Linux

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox

I have installed tinycore in VirtualBox. However, I am not satisfied with the boot time. From what I have investigated so far, this is due to the frugal install. All packages are compressed and reside in one folder and are unpacked and installed everytime during boot. Depending on how many packages you want to be available on boot this may take some time. I would prefer it, if the packages would be persistent and that the root filesystem would not have to be repopulated after every boot.

Is there a way to make a "real", non-frugal install of tinycore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: "no".  Tiny Core is explicitly designed *not* to be installed the way you are contemplating.

However, there are some considerations you should take into account:

1. Tiny Core does not "unpack" packages ("extensions" in Tiny Core parlance).  Instead, each extension is a mountable, compressed, read-only filesystem which is simply mounted, and the individual files within it are symlinked into their appropriate positions (usually under `/usr`) rather than being copied there.
2. The process in step one has several advantages

   1. the files take up very little actual memory space under `/usr`
   2. the files are reasonably safe/secure as they are read-only
   3. creating symbolic links is *much* faster than copying the files
3. Given the above, particularly item 2.3, there may be some other factor slowing down your VM's boot – anything from the physical hardware to the underlying OS on which VirtualBox is running.

If you want to continue down the path of a "real" install (what the Tiny Core designer refers to as "Scatter Mode" because files are scattered all over the disk), you might want to try one of the following:

- remaster the initrd to contain your extensions, preloaded.  This will still not get you the disk based system you wanted as the entire filesystem will be in RAM – possibly a lot of RAM.
- Load the extensions with the copy-to-fs option (which will eat up a lot of RAM) and then somehow image the running file system – but you still need to figure out how to get it running on disk.
- (Probably the cleanest option) Use a different distro, as you would really be losing the most important benefits of Tiny Core anyway.